# Positioning form controls within a Liferay portlet (using bootstrap or other)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, liferay-6

I am developing a portlet and I would like to use bootstrap to give it a nice look.

I can load and use the bootstrap CSS classes and JS scripts correctly.
However, the `col-xs-12`, `col-sm-12` ... classes, which I usually use to position controls into forms, do not seem to work.

For instance:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-12" id="test" placeholder="teest2">
```

...does NOT display the input with width =100% of portlet's width.
It sticks to 15% or so of the portlet's width.

How can I solve this?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you try col-md-12 for default view?

Comment: Share the rendered HTML. By my experience, Liferay inserts tons of crap of unuseful html. Maybe you missed the `row` class

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zpLo3jby/

Comment: Using col-md-12  does not work better than col-xs-12

Comment: Using a <div class="row"> div does not solve the problem:
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-12" id="test10" placeholder="teest10">
 </div>
 </div>

Comment: Liferay 6 uses [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/), the CSS classes that you are talking about are Bootstrap 3...

Comment: Thanks Tobias.
And I take it there was no equivalent attributes in bootstrap 2 ? :(

Comment: So for further reference,  we need to use spanX and offsetX instead of col-xs-X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I found out that Liferay (6.2 at this stage) does not support bootstrap 3.
It only supports bootstrap2 so you need to set control size with:
class = "span12" to class = "span1"